# Exclude specific product category from Woocommerce related products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I Have done some searching around excluding a product category from related products in Woocommerce. But all the answers to this problem relate to excluding completely categories and/or tags.

How do I hook into woocommerce_get_related_products to exclude a specific product category?

I would like to exclude my **"Sold"** product category from displayed related products.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
add_action( 'wp', 'vn_remove_related_products' );
function vn_remove_related_products() {
  if ( is_product() && has_term( array('workshops', 'events'), 'product_cat' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
  }
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more details visit

[remove a category from related products](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/293917/woocommerce-exclude-specific-categories-products-from-related-products)

[Woocommerce exclude specific category products from related products](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109455/woocommerce-exclude-specific-category-products-from-related-products)

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for something that will hook directly into the query

Comment: @RichardTinkler please check the second link.